# How to guide users to the correct download?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, conversion, download, decision-making

I'm new to StackExchange and found this page because I have an unsolved problem:

We have several products. For this we offer two setups for download. One is for some sort of file synchronization (like DropBox) and the other one is for secure email communication. Sadly, there are always users who simply click the first button they find. It turns out that they do not read a single sentence on that page. And for some of them it is obviously the wrong setup. But then they create huge support effort because they give unclear error description until it turns out they're using the wrong tool...

How would you guide them? I considered some "Download assistant", but I doubt that they would read this. Any other ideas?

This is how it currently looks like:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/9ov1avl.png]

The "Other downloads" link offers other OS (Windows is auto-detected).

Any idea about how I can better guide them? Sadly, it is about 50-50. So half of the users needs the one, the other half the other setup. It does not help to prioritize one.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Welcome to the community :) My first response would be to change the product names or logo's. As they both start with Regi, it's easy for a user to make such a mistake. But I guess you want an easier solution.

Comment: Yeah, regi... is the brand and all products start with this (regimail, regibox, regichat, regibill, regipay etc). "regi" is for registered and marks the core functionality (register and certify -> regify). I know that this might confuse people, but we can not change. The images are not logos. They were meant to help users understand the purpose (with no success). They can be changed to something better. Any suggestions here?

Comment: Try different colors. It's one big blue blurb now. Use blue for the overall company coloring and supporting colors for the different products.

Answer (score 4):

**While the best UX would be to combine both softwares** (don't become a second Axosoft), the easiest way would be to ask them on the landing or on the download site something like:

What do you need **product branch name** for? and give them either to choose or dropdown and give them the correct software.

Alternatively you can show them the most likely product based on their referer, cookies or if they are logged in thanks to the information about what product they bought. Use all the information about the user you have and can (legally) get.

Does the user come to your website after **searching for e-mail security on google?** Present them the regimail. Where they looking for dropbox alternatives? You know what to do.

You can also **track their conersion funnel** on your website. What pages have they been on and what button or link on which site was the last click they did before being directed to the download site. Use the power of data.

A general analysis of userdata followed by a cleanup of your interface could help you, too.

Comment: Hi. This contains some good points and ideas. Sadly, download is without login and therefore we do not know. Please see my comment from the above post. But considering history and/or forwarders may be at least some indicator to present the one or the other as first option... We already considered some "Download Assistant" but I doubt the people will ready anything. They will just click "Next" and "Next" and download whatever comes...

Comment: Then force the people to read. Instead of giving them a linear download funnel, consider forcing them to choose from the download site. Not really talking about a assistant. Directly on the site, like "Welcome to the download page. Do you want to send encrypted emails or save your files online" or something like that.

Comment: Thanks Marvin, but we've had this before. People still did not read. They simply picked the first option - they would even pick "I sell my soul to the devil" without even noticing. The only thing that comes to my mind is some sort of captcha, where thinking and reading is needed to get to the next step. But that would really annoying people...

Comment: If your users are really THAT extremely "lazy" (which I can't believe) then the problem has to be at your whole funnel. You should get someone to analyze your funnels, having a look at the useage data and improve your site with some A/B testings. In the meanwhile, force people to go through a Q&A/FAQ before reaching to the support. This way you can filter them through the most common problems which would include that.

Comment: I agree with @marvinpoo here. It seems your entire funnel has some big issues. And people tend to not care about what they choose.

Comment: Yah, we already did that sort of support direction. It is only about 5 users from 1000, but they generate support effort far from being economical. Sometimes, especially for regipay (payslips) these users are cleaners, janitors and security guards. Not all of them ever finished a school and some of them even have problems reading the language. But they use a smartphone or PC and want to use the software to get and read their payslips (the right one). Some of them downloading the regibox software and hitting support on a large scale...

Comment: There you have it, they want to read their payslips. Not download some software :)

Answer (score 2):

A bit of an alternative route. It seems the product is unclear to users, which stops them from reading or researching what they actually need.

**Solution 1**

Create a simple questionnaire on the website, where people have to go through a simple funnel that makes them reach the correct product. That could be as simple as:

1. What would you like to do? (send secure emails / safely store my files)

**Solution 2**

Put the phonenumber on your website and have people call you. Let them explain their question and give them the correct link. That could be either website.com/regify or website.com/regibox.

Comment: Thanks Matthijs. Solution one we already tried. But the simply choosing first option and continue without even reading the question... Solution 2 sounds like a support nightmare. We earn only a few cent per user and picking up the phone for such user will destroy any business model. We need all users to find the right download by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Put a download button on each product page instead of both buttons on a separate download page.

Comment: Could you expand on your post. As it is it's more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Thanks, but the two products are managed from one portal. The users get an account (with portal) and can book one or more products. There are no separate product pages. The download is also available without login. But even if logged in, we do not know what download the user will need because even if regibox is not booked, you still can install and be a member of other users regiboxes. Its all users decision.

We already tried to find indicators for the best download, but we do not have such.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what exactly product it is but the text and pictures don't help at all to people who aren't clear on what you are offering. I gather that they have to download some sort of client, but using your branding doesn't help them, as far as users are concerned, they have Outlook/DropBox/whatever. So you need "Download DropBox connector" or "Download Email Client" type buttons instead.

And if users are still just clicking the first option first, then you need to put the most compatible (i.e. what most users will have) solution first.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to the community!

Of course users always do their worst. it is their job! Our job is to design to reduce their error rate :)

Some problems I quickly detected here:
1. Too much text. As you already realized, users do not read any single line of text. You designed this page beliving they will diligently read and put effort to understand. As said, they do not. They simply click the first button they see. Try to summarize all text in just 2 words each product ("sincronize files").

2. Low visual difference between the two products. You can not tell the difference with just a glance. And most of the time is all we get from users. Try to use different colors for Regibox and Regimail. Like the choice between the login with social networks
   [image]
3. The two icons (or logos?) are too similar, again they do not quickly (like 200ms) gave the idea that we are looking at two different products. Use perceptive hints to suggest this difference (colors, placement, shapes)

Most probably you will just reduce the error rate, but you will keep high the conversion rate since the buttons are quickly available on the page.

Comment: Thanks Marco. Also some valid points. We will have a look for sure.